# coding style - consensus about the use of properties

Tags: typescript

Here are 2 versions of the same class.

**1) With a public field:**

```
export class MyClass {
  public field: string;
}
```

**2) With getter and setter**:

```
export class MyClass {
  private _field: string;

  public get field() {
    return this._field;
  }

  public set field(field: string) {
    this._field = field;
  }
}
```

**Comparing to another language:**

If this was a java or C# class, - the general consensus - would be that public fields (i.e. code block 1) violate the law of encapsulation. On top of that, in java, there are some differences in how fields behave in case of multi-threading. You may need to add the `volatile` keyword if you want to access a field directly.

So, in java and C# the consensus is that you should write getters/setters in most cases. (i.e. code block 2)

**In typescript, getters/setters seem to have more disadvantages than advantages:**

But I have the impression that in Typescript it may actually be better to just make the **fields** public. It seems to solve some issues:

- for an external class, calling a field or a getter looks entirely the same (hence, there are no braces when calling a getter).
- my example above defines fields with underscore prefixes, which is a violation of the naming convention for fields.
- avoid potential mistakes that cause recursive loops. `get f() { return f; }`
- obviously, less repetitive boilerplate code: Most of my typescript classes are almost empty (i.e. classes for angular components). If I were to define all getters/setters explicitly, that would probably triple the amount of code.

**Some specific questions:**

- What's the general consensus in the Typescript community about properties ?
- When all this typescript code is build to javascript, could it be that both pieces of code actually just result in the same javascript code?

*Why am I asking questions about style ? - Because I don't just write code for myself. I also want others to enjoy my code, without feeling annoyed because I'm violating simple coding rules.*

Comment: I guess it depends on how you and your team write code. Personally, I have an implicit contract with myself (and anyone working with me) to treat every object as readonly, except in tight loops where performance demands otherwise. Since data has no associated behavior, there is nothing to encapsulate.

Comment: For the person who flagged this question as "opinion based": then why is there a "naming-convention" tag ?

Comment: I personally use setters and getters only if there is some more logic/code in their body